# VBA finds cell range error

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting in the range as follows MyRange=f2:g10, I would like how i would able to go through f1,f2 ect. where the question mark is. how am i able to do this,

```
Function CountRed(MyRange As Range)
CountRed = 0

Range(?).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: The name of your function would suggest that you actually want to count which cells have an interior color of red, but the code looks like you're trying to set the color to red. Could you clarify?

Comment: I first need to make the range get colored based on the values that are in the cell and then  count the number of reds in the range,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the colour all in one go:

```
MyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

or create a Range variable and loop through each cell:

```
Dim rng as Range

For Each rng In MyRange
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next rng
```

Comment: You can also set it with a single integer value using `Interior.ColorIndex`. http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: 3 is for red. This is fine if sticking with standard colours - ColorIndex only goes upto 56.

Comment: Yeah. I like it simple. :)

Comment: Yes it does. If, however, you are attempting to use a VBA function in Excel to modify cells it won't work. VBA functions don't work this way - to modify cells requires a Sub procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **sub** rather than a **UDF:**

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("F2:G10")
    Call CountRed(MyRange)
End Sub

Sub CountRed(r As Range)
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

I would use a **sub** rather than a **UDF** because:

- no value is being returned
- worksheets cells are being modified

For more tutorial info see [OZGRID UDF Training](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson21.htm)

Comment: I think you should add a note as to why this is preferable.